# Graph API Check IN

Tags: php, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, checkin

Hi I am developing an application that will communicate with Facebook Graph API to check in user at a particular location (only one).

1) I let the user sign in, and ask for authorization to publish/sign into locations
2) I get the token from facebook and thus acquire the credentials

How do I check in a user? at a location ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to have `publish_checkins` authorization for the user. If you get that you can simply do a post to `http://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/checkins` which take several parameters. Please check publishing section of this [page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/).

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
 -F 'message=The coffee is just meh.' \
 -F 'place=PAGE_ID' \
 -F 'coordinates={"latitude":"...", "longitude": "..."}' \
 -F 'tags=USER_ID1, USER_ID2' \
 https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This is a tool to call a url in commandline. I am not sure about windows system but Unix systems have adopted this. More [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: BTW if any answer help you, you should accept that or do a upvote.

Comment: Hey guys quick question, If I have the PAGE_ID are the lat/long coordinates necessary?

Comment: How I can do using C# SDK is there any idea.!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve same thing in the Facebook JavaScript SDK. You need "publish_checkins" Extended permission in [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)

```
FB.api('/me/checkins', 'post', 
       { message: 'Hurrey, At Facebook HQ...!!!',
           place: 110506962309835,
           coordinates: {
               'latitude': 37.4163458217,
               'longitude': -122.15198690595
           }
       },
       function (response) {
           console.log(response.id);
       }
);
```